# Compile Java DIO for 64-bit ARM

Tags: java, c, raspberry-pi

I would like to compile Java DIO library for 64-bit ARM. (Raspberry Pi Model 3B)

I used following instruction to install Java, C compilator, and compile the DIO library:
[image]

After success compilation I have copied Java DIO and C (native) DIO libraries to JRE:
[image]

Then test was run and received error message:
[image]

Error stated "**wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)**".

But I see in Mercury log that developers have ported library to 64-bit platform:
https://hg.openjdk.org/dio/dev

[image]

How I can compile the DIO library for 64-bit ARM?

Comment: Previously I have successfully compiled the Java DIO for 32-bit ARM with exactly the same instruction. Only change was used 32-bit Java "jdk-8u351-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.tar.gz".